# Custom template order by id issue

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort post by ID in ASC order, I'm able to do that when I use single query but when use array query I'm unbale to sort post by ID in ASC order my code looks like below

```
  <?php
    $ourCurrentPage = get_query_var('paged');
    $newposts = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name'  => 'stock-market-basics',
    'orderby'    => 'ID',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'paged'      => $ourCurrentPage
    ));
  ?>
  <?php 
    if ($newposts->have_posts()):
    while ($newposts->have_posts()):
    $newposts->the_post();
  ?>
```

// Some display code and after closing code //

```
  <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no results matched your criteria.' ); ?</p>
  <?php endif; ?>

            <li><?php 
              echo paginate_links(array(
                'total' => $newposts->max_num_pages
              ));
            ?></li>
```

Comment: You want to display category query listing order by ID?

Comment: Yes but it's a custom template for category. Please suggest that will be very helpful

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress query by category name

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'author'       => '',
    'author_name'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>


// Custom query.
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check that we have query results.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // Start looping over the query results.
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        // Contents of the queried post results go here.

    }

}
```

Hope this works for you.